# Lexical error when connecting R with Jupyter Notebook by IRkernel::installspec()

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I want to connect R with Jupyter Notebook, and I have installed `IRkernel`. However, when I run the code `IRkernel::installspec()`, an error occurs:

> Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
>                                         C:\Users\xin_chen\AppData\Local
>                       (right here) ------^

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on one of my machines. I ended up manually copying the kernelspec files from another PC. The path is:

```
C:\Users\_username_\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\ir
```

If you don't have a working installation, you can copy the files from 
https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/tree/master/inst/kernelspec.

You might need to edit the `kernel.json` file to set the path of your R executable. For example:

```
{
  "argv": ["C:/Program Files/Microsoft/R Client/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R", "--slave", "-e", "IRkernel::main()", "--args", "{connection_file}"],
  "display_name": "R",
  "language": "R"
}
```